# Getting News letter on everypage

Tags: magento-1.9

Please see the below images I'm getting newsletter in every products page please help me in removing this.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to

`System->Configuration->Advanced->Advanced` search for `mage_newsletter` `disable it`.

Refresh Cache & Reindex Data

Hope this helps.

Comment: mann you made my day it worked thankyouu :)

Comment: Glad my answer was useful. :)